# VBA Excel: Call sub in form from module

Tags: vba, excel

I want to call a function in a form from a function in a modul

So I defined the function Init_StockForm() in the form (which is called Form):

```
    Public Sub Init_StockForm()

      MsgBox ("Bla")

    End Sub
```

I call that function in the module as follows:

```
    Form.Init_StockForm
```

but this results in a Runtime error 91

So what's wrong here?
Thanks form help

Comment: And why would you use such abomination? Why not just define the sub in a code module, where it belongs? Anyway, I'm not sure you can do this, as seen from your example. General subs have no place inside the form's module, just like they have nothing to do in a sheet's module.

Comment: It works fine for me if I call it using that one line from a sub in a regular module. Don't be discouraged by @vacip's rather harsh response, but do perhaps show more code to help us troubleshoot.

Comment: The reason why I want to call a function from the formular in the modul is the following:
I have a button in the excel sheet which executes a macro (so I have a function in the Module) but this function Init_StockForm() is in the Form because it needs to access all the elements of the form. This Init_StockForm() uses update functions which I also need in the Form, this is why I want to execute a function from Form in the Module. So if you @vacip have a better idea to realice that, your wellcome to post it

Comment: You can do anything and everything on a form from a standard module - provided that the form exists (it is running). So just put the code in a standard code module, it should work fine. Putting a sub in a form's module and then calling it from outside is a bit upside-down for me. Still, it is supposed to work that way, however messy it looks.

Answer (score 0):

make a new instance of your form (VBA is object oriented Programming Language)

module:

```
Private Sub callFormSub()
Dim myForm As New UserForm1
myForm.subInUserForm
End Sub
```

Form:

```
Public Sub subInUserForm()
MsgBox "BLA"
End Sub
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but note that it's not necessary, at least in Excel 2016.

Comment: It also serves little purpose if you use `Dim ... As New` since you're creating an auto-instantiating variable for a class that already is auto-instantiating.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers
Today the solution I posted also works ( :/ ) the reason might be a bug on my installation, since the macro shows also a very strange behaviour in an other function, but I will post that later in an other post if I can't solve it

Comment: Since this seems to be caused a bug, you might want to consider deleting the question - it is unlikely to help anyone in the future, being a one-time, non-reproducible bug. _"A problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"_ - we usually close or delete questions like this here. See a discussion about a similar case [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256475/delete-own-question-after-it-works-randomly), if you are interested. No harm done if you decide not to delete it, but it will likely be closed anyway.